# Controle de orientação

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Defini a orientação de uma pagina da minha app como paisagem, porém a mesma ficou estática. Se o usuário virar a tela **180º** continua como paisagem mas fica de **ponta cabeça**.
Como faço para que quando o aparelho seja rotacionado a tela continue em paisagem e acompanhe a posição de visão do usuário ?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione utilize dessa forma:

***Exemplo:***

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;
}
```